# Adding an item to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I had a List<> of my objects, but now need to change it to an IEnumerable<>. So, I have this:

```
public IEnumerable<TransactionSplitLine> TransactionSplitLines { get; set; }
```

However, I can no longer do:

```
reply.TransactionSplitLines.Add(new TransactionSplitLine
                                                    {Amount = "100", Category = "Test", SubCategory = "Test More", CategoryId=int.Parse(c)});
```

How should I be adding items now?

Comment: What motivated the change from `List<>` to `IEnumerable<>`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I think I need to, for this bit of code to work, which loads a partial view. Html.EditorFor(m=>m.TransactionSplitLines)

Comment: why? `IList<>` is `IEnumberable<>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add an item to a IEnumerable<T> collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210295/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-ienumerablet-collection)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could do something like the following, using Concat:

```
reply.TransactionSplitLines = 
    reply.TransactionSplitLines.Concat(new []{new TransactionSplitLine                                                     {
                                                 Amount = "100", 
                                                 Category = "Test", 
                                                 SubCategory = "Test More",
                                                 CategoryId = int.Parse(c)}});
```

That basically creates a new `IEnumerable`. It's hard to say what's the *best* solution in your case, since there are not enough information about your use case.

**EDIT:**
Please note that `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. So if you need to pass an `IEnumerable<T>` as a parameter for example, you can also pass a `List<T>` instead, maybe calling explicitly [`AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) on your list first. So maybe you could stick with a List instead of an IEnumerable.

Comment: This is the best answer, if the intention is that callers shouldn't be making persistent changes to this `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: This will result in a new Enumerable and will not change the old one.

Comment: Curiously, I gave the same answer (before this one) then I deleted it... Anyway I think it could be really inefficient if `Add` operations are very frequent

Comment: @Itay Yes, this creates a new IEnumerable, like i said in my answer. I also said that this maybe not the best solution. It really depends on information that are not avaiable.

Comment: @dkson: +1 Sorry, I missed it :)

Comment: The upside of this method is that it will work when the OP needs to add few items (you always think you won't need it until you suddenly do). The downside is that it requires TreansactionSplitLines to be mutable.

Comment: Another problem of this approach comes out if someone keeps the reference of the IEnumerable returned from property before another one change it.

Comment: Thank you. Your note "Please note that List<T> implements IEnumerable<T>" REALLY helped.

Answer (score 9):

**Short answer:** You can't add items to `IEnumerable<T>`

**Slightly longer explanation:**

`IEnumerable` is an interface that is solely concerned about being able to enumerate/iterate over the collection of items. This is the only purpose of an existence of `IEnumerable`. It abstracts away any notion of the manner of storing or retrieving the enumerable items (it might be a string of characters, list of items, a stream of bytes or series of a computation results), thus if you have an interface that is an `IEnumerable`, you can't add items to it, you can only iterate across the items it provides.

That said, the *correct* way to add items to `IEnumerable` is to return new `IEnumerable` with the new items appended to the contents of the original.

Also with Linq libraries you have an extension method that allows casting your IEnumerable to a List via `IEnumerable.ToList()` and you can add items to a list. THis moght not be the proper way though.

With Linq libraries in your namespace you can do the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace EnumTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             IEnumerable<string> enum = GetObjectEnumerable();

             IEnumerable<string> concatenated = enum.Concat(new List<string> { "concatenated" });

             List<string> stringList = concatenated.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot add items to `IEnumerable<T>` since this interface does not have an `Add` method.
if `TransactionSplitLines` always return an instance of a `List<TransactionSplitLine>` you might want to change its type to `IList<TransactionSplitLine>`.
In case you cannot change the type of `TransactionSplitLines` and you can guarantee that it is always return a `IList<TransactionSplitLines>` you can cast it as in

```
((IList<TransactionSplitLine>)reply.TransactionSplitLines).Add(new TransactionSplitLine
                                                    {Amount = "100", Category = "Test", SubCategory = "Test More", CategoryId=int.Parse(c)});
```

Comment: @Mudo: I would go for the `IList<T>` rather than `IList`

Answer (score 3):

[`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) doesn't have an `Add(T)` method. Depending on your real type, you could cast it like this:

```
var item = new TransactionSplitLine {Amount = "100", Category = "Test", SubCategory = "Test More", CategoryId=int.Parse(c)};

((IList)reply.TransactionSplitLines).Add(item);
```

**If** the collection you are using implements `IList`.

Remember that you want to use most basic Interface / Class when you pass your objects around. So if you need to use methods from `IList` I would suggest you use that instead of `IEnumerable`.

I would suggest you do the following Change:

```
public IList<TransactionSplitLine> TransactionSplitLines { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what is the meaning and purpose of your `TransactionSplitLines` property.

If you want to allow editing (adding/removing) from the outside of you class, well just make your property less generic than `IEnumerable<T>` for example:

```
public IList<TransactionSplitLine> TransactionSplitLines { get; set; }
```

or better:

```
public ICollection<TransactionSplitLine> TransactionSplitLines { get; set; }
```

---

Instead, if you need just to edit the collection internally (I mean in the class scope), why don't you do something like this:

```
private List<TransactionSplitLine> transactionSplitLines;

public IEnumerable<TransactionSplitLine> TransactionSplitLines 
{ 
  get
  {
     return transactionSplitLines;
  }
}
```

so you can use `transactionSplitLines` field to change the collection internally.

Comment: If he just wants add it's more readable to use IList than using Concat, imho.

Answer (score 2):

I would create this extension method, which does all that lazily:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] items)
{
    return source.Concat(items);
}
```

So in your case:

```
var item = new TransactionSplitLine { Amount = "100", Category = "Test", 
                                      SubCategory = "Test More", 
                                      CategoryId = int.Parse(c) };
reply.TransactionSplitLines.Append(item);
```

You can have `Prepend` as well similarly:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] items)
{
    return items.Concat(source);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Concat` method for concatenating two sets like that:

```
reply.TransactionSplitlines = reply.TransactionSplitlines.Concat(/* another enumerable */);
```

You would need to write an extension method `AsEnumerable` which would take an `obj` and do something like `yield return obj;`. You can avoid writing an extension method and just pass `new []` with an object in it to the `Concat` method, but if your interface is based on `IEnumerable`, it's likely that you'll need the `AsEnumerable` method in some other cases too.

That's if you really need it to be `IEnumerable`. However, I would advise to consider switching to `IList<T>` or some other interface that supports `add`. If you need to implement some interface by having the `IEnumerable<>` property, you can have the `IList<>` as an inner field for this property and modify it separately - the odds are that you are working with concrete object here, not the interface. If you are working with the interface and still need to use `Add`, `IEnumerable<>` is just a bad choice of type for this interface.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable is immutable collection, it means you cannot add, or remove item. Extension method creates a new instance.(Explained with an eg here: [What's the Best Way to Add One Item to an IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251159/whats-the-best-way-to-add-one-item-to-an-ienumerablet) )
Rather, then creating Extension method, one can initially add to list like below:
eg In my case User Roles are defined as IEnumerable(in User model class). So, in order to add in value to that Role. Initially I had defined a list :

```
List<Role> rols=new List<Role>();
```

Inside for loop added value to this list like:

```
foreach(int i=0;i<chkRoles.count;i++)
{
 Role r=new Role();
r.RoleId="2";
r.RoleName="Admin";
rols.add(r);
}
```

and then provide this value to IEnumerable ist:

```
user.Roles=rols.AsEnumerable();
```