# What's the Best Way to Add One Item to an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ienumerable

Here's how I would add one item to an IEnumerable object:

```
//Some IEnumerable<T> object
IEnumerable<string> arr = new string[] { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI" };

//Add one item
arr = arr.Concat(new string[] { "JKL" });
```

This is awkward.  I don't see a method called something like `ConcatSingle()` however.

Is there a cleaner way to add a single item to an IEnumerable object?

Comment: @Chris: I rolled that back. There is a reason that feature has been removed from SO.

Comment: Didn't realize that feature has been added.  Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nope, that's about as concise as you'll get using built-in language/framework features.

You could always create an extension method if you prefer:

```
arr = arr.Append("JKL");
// or
arr = arr.Append("123", "456");
// or
arr = arr.Append("MNO", "PQR", "STU", "VWY", "etc", "...");

// ...

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] tail)
    {
        return source.Concat(tail);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is such method in System.Linq namespace

Answer (score 9):

`IEnumerable` is *immutable* collection, it means you cannot add, or remove item. Instead, you *have to* create a new collection for this, simply to convert to list to add:

```
var newCollection = arr.ToList();
newCollection.Add("JKL"); //is your new collection with the item added
```

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something....but Add does not return the new list....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3wcytfd1(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: `Add` doesn't return the new list but because `List` is a *mutable* collection you can simply reference the `List` object to access the 'new list'. This answer is slightly pedantic in that sense (because it's mostly obvious that the OP was asking how to create a new `IEnumerable` from another `IEnumerable` and one additional object).

Comment: > `IEnumerable` is *immutable* collection -- That's wrong, it is not a collection, it's an interface. An object of a class that implements it may be immutable (like Array) or mutable (like List<T>), this depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 8):

Write an extension method `ConcatSingle` :)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatSingle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item)
{
    return source.Concat(new [] { item } );
}
```

But you need to be more careful with your terminology.
You can't add an item to an `IEnumerable<T>`. `Concat` creates a new instance.

Example:

```
var items = Enumerable.Range<int>(1, 10)
Console.WriteLine(items.Count()); // 10
var original= items;
items = items.ConcatSingle(11);
Console.WriteLine(original.Count());   // 10
Console.WriteLine(items.Count()); // 11
```

As you can see, the original enumeration - which we saved in `original` didn't change.

Answer (score 7):

Since [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) is read-only, you need to convert to list.

```
var new_one = arr.ToList().Add("JKL");
```

Or you can get a *[extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)* like;

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] item)
{
    return source.Concat(item);
}
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is read-only.  That does not mean it is immutable.  An immutable collection is one that will never change.  An `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't even promise that the reference can't be typecast to a mutable type, much less that the underlying collection won't change.

Answer (score 3):

`Append()` - is exactly what you need, it has been added to the .NET Standard (in 2017), so you no longer need to write your own extension methods. You can simply do this:

`arr = arr.Append("JKL");`

Since .NET is open source, here you can look on the implementation (it is more sophisticated than custom methods suggested above):
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/AppendPrepend.cs

Comment: Interesting, Thanks.  It looks like the new .Net version is attaching linked lists to the beginning and end of the given IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning an array to an IEnumerable. Why don't you use the Array type instead of IEnumerable?

Otherwise you can use IList (or List) if you want to change the collection.

I use IEnumerable only for methods params when I need to read and IList (or List) when I need to change items in it.