# How to add a row to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have an object **result** of type IEnumerable and an object **res** of type Object.
I want to concatenate both, how can i do

```
IEnumerable<V_Student_Attendace_DayWise> result;
V_Student_Attendace_DayWise res;
result.Concat(res); // Error here...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the Best Way to Add One Item to an IEnumerable<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251159/whats-the-best-way-to-add-one-item-to-an-ienumerablet)

Comment: What kind of error do you get? If you try exactly like in your code snippet, then you try to work with uninitialized variables. This is not possible in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Enumerable.Concat` method expect a collection as its argument, so you have to give the input as a collection in order to get it concatinated. So the code for this will looks like the following, where `res` the object that you already having

```
result = result.Concat(new[] { res});
```

You can try this as well:

```
result = result.Concat(new[] { new V_Student_Attendace_DayWise()});
```

Comment: Now there is no error but in result new row did not cancat, result remain same

Comment: see my updates in the answer, try assign concatenated value back to result

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped. happy codding

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
result.ToList().Add(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers given are good, but please be aware that you're not tacking new items onto the end of your `IEnumerable`. You are creating a **new** collection that consists of the old collection with the new item tacked on at the end. (If the collection that implements `IEnumerable` happens to implement `IList` as well, you could cast and `Add` for improved performance and memory usage, but different semantics.)