# Using IEnumerable<T> to add instances of an object in .net core

Tags: .net, .net-core, enumerable

I need to add an object to an IEnumerable but not 100% sure how to do it. It appears .add isn't working for me in my .net core 3.1 code.

The first class is this:

```
 public class ContainerA
{
    public string TestA { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ContainerB> Containers { get; set; }
}
```

Then there is the ContainerB class:

```
public class ContainerB
{
    public string TextString { get; set; }
}
```

I am unsure about how to add a bunch of Continers of object ContainerB to the instance object of ContainerA, like so:

```
var contA = new ContainerA();

contA.TestA = "works fine";

// Issues here and how to get lots of ContainerB.TestString into the contA instance.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use the `.Concat` or `.Append` extension methods.

Comment: The exact duplciate [How can I add an item to a IEnumerable<T> collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210295/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-ienumerablet-collection) as well as [Adding an item to IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026483/adding-an-item-to-ienumerable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable` does not support additions, if you want to able to add you can use [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=netcore-3.1) or [`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=netcore-3.1) for `Containers` property type. If you want to stick with `IEnumerable` - you can create new  one via [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netcore-3.1) (or [`Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netcore-3.1) to add single element) and assign it to `Containers`:

```
IEnumerable<ContainerB> toAdd = ...; //  lots of ContainerB.TestString
contA.Containers = contA.Containers
    .Concat(toAdd);
```

Comment: @cdub I think they might have possibly fixed this in .NET Core, but at least with .NET Framework, always be careful when using `IList` this way.  It *should* work...but at least in .NET Framework, arrays implemented `IList`, but then they throw exceptions if you use things like `IList.Add`.  That doesn't mean `IList` shouldn't be used this way; it *should*.  Just be cautious that it's not implemented by an array, because of a design decision made way back when.