# (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Name not working in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a code below in my controller:

```
var getAllModel =
            VehicleManager.GetAllModelsByMakeId(getMakeId.MakeId)
                .Select(c => new SelectListItem {Text = c.Name, Value = c.ModelId.ToString()})
                .ToList();
var getAllTrim =
            VehicleManager.GetAllTrimByModelId(getModelId.ModelId)
                .Select(c => new SelectListItem {Text = c.Name, Value = c.TrimId.ToString()}).ToList();

ViewBag.ModelName = getAllModel;
ViewBag.TrimName= getAllTrim;
```

and in my .cshtml page also below:

```
var trimName = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ModelName;
var modelName = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TrimName;
```

Now i want to insert a `trimName.Insert(0, new SelectListItem {Text= "Select", Value = ""})` but failed to access.

here's the problem i encountered: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
Anyone has a suggestion or explanation on this?

Comment: i will edit the question with the issue

Comment: see my post it will help

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Sorry Guys, i solved the problem by changing the Class Bind to a certain List Before the declared problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` as `IEnumerable<T>` is sequential, From a SO answer:

> > The purpose of the IEnumerable interface is to allow a consumer to view the contents of a collection. Not to modify the values.

```
var trimName = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ModelName;
var modelName = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TrimName;
```

See this [**SO post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210295/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-ienumerablet-collection) to know why you cannot add item in `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: @JedMonsanto but why do you want to append values to your data inside of the view.

Comment: @JedMonsanto what is it you are trying to insert, do you need a default value, is that your goal ?

Comment: make sure ViewBag.Model is not null it looks like it is coming null

Comment: a Select word only... but beside, i cannot apply the insert in any of those variable like: trimName.Insert

Comment: Sorry Guys, i solved the problem by changing the Class Bind to a certain List Before the declared problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to add an empty item to the select list, then there's a much easier way. `Html.DropDownListFor` takes a parameter to set up an empty item for you:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TrimName, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TrimNameChoices, "Select an Option...")
```

Also, notice that I changed the name of your `ViewBag` variable. If your property on your model is `TrimName` you can't store your select list in `ViewBag.TrimName` or it will clobber any selected value.  It's always better, if you're going to use `ViewBag` at all for select lists, to name them with something like `Choices` or `Options` at the end, so you don't have to worry about collisions like this.

Comment: Sorry Guys, i solved the problem by changing the Class Bind to a certain List Before the declared problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Trim Name")]
public string TrimName{ get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
var getAllTrim =
            VehicleManager.GetAllTrimByModelId(getModelId.ModelId)
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem {Text = c.Name, Value = c.TrimId.ToString()})
        .ToList();

ViewBag.TrimList= getAllTrim;
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TrimName, 
                  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TrimList, "-- Select --")
```

Comment: Sorry Guys, i solved the problem by changing the Class Bind to a certain List Before the declared problem