# Why IEnumerable needs to implement Add but no other methods?

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
class Salaries : IEnumerable
{
    List<double> salaries = new List<double>();

    public Salaries()
    {
    }

    public void Insert(double salary)
    {
        salaries.Add(salary);
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return salaries.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

In the program I try to add some values like this:

```
Salaries mySalaries = new Salaries() { 1000, 2000, 3000 };
```

I get this error:

> 'Salaries' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'Salaries' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why do I get this error?

Where can I find (using VS) that I need to implement `Add` function?

If I look in the List definition, I can see more functions, so why the compiler wants me to implement `Add`?

(I know that if I change the method in the class from Insert to Add it's OK. But the question is why only add, and where does it come from?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add an item to a IEnumerable<T> collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210295/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-ienumerablet-collection)

Comment: Why don't you just rename Insert to Add and get it over with?   It is a misleading name anyway since it doesn't actually "insert", it only appends.

Comment: Please read my post again. Especialy the last part.

Comment: Please read my comment again.  Especially the last part.  The only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are calling the `Add` method when you use a collection initializer.

```
Salaries mySalaries = new Salaries() { 1000, 2000, 3000 };
```

is translated by the compiler to:

```
Salaries mySalaries = new Salaries();
mySalaries.Add(1000);
mySalaries.Add(2000);
mySalaries.Add(3000);
```

Comment: See also the documentation on MSDN on [Collection initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx#Anchor_2) which explains this

Comment: Or the C# spec, for the definitive answer.

Comment: So why don't I get the same error when I do this: List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

Comment: @NoamB. Because `List<int>` has an Add method. Your Salaries class does not.