# Method is returning List when the method return type IEnumerable.But GetType shows as List

Tags: c#, generics, collections

Though, the below question seems to be silly, but still it would help others also. I have method that return a list.And the method return type IEnumnerable.
Method:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons()
        {
            List<Person> personList = new List<Person>()
                                          {
                                              new Person() { Age = 10, Name = "Vijay"}
                                          };

           return personList;

        }
    }
```

Now whenever I am calling this method and checking the type.The output is

```
System.Collections.Generic.List
```

Since it is a List. I should be able add Items to the list. But system is throwing a compilation error.
Below is the execution part:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] ar)
        {
            var personList = Person.GetPersons();
            Console.WriteLine(personList.GetType()); //System.Collections.Generic.List
            personList.Add(new Person(){Age = 11, Name = "Ajay"}); // Compilation error
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

So could anyone help me with the understanding. It would be great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at [How can I add an item to a IEnumerable<T> collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1210318/2417602).... it might help you understand.

Comment: Think of `IEnumerable` as a **mask** over the underlying type (i.e. List). I mean a physical mask (like Darth Vader's mask). The ienumerable **itself** knows what it is (i.e. it knows it is a list). But the **caller** / **user** of it doesn't. So the caller / user can only interact with the ienumerable with methods available to **all** ienumerables. Why does the compiler work this way? Well, just because the thing behind the mask is **today** a `List` doesn't mean it always will be. Tomorrow, the implementation might change - it might be an array (which doesn't support `Add`).

Comment: But whenever the caller calls the method and gets the type of the method. It stil shows as **System.Collections.Generic.List<T>** . Could you explain why  GetType is showing as List<T>

Comment: Because you are asking the object what it really is. It knows what it is under the mask, at **runtime** (just like if you wear a Darth Vader mask and someone asks your name - you know your name, but the person speaking to you doesn't unless you tell them - which is basically what `GetType` is doing). But the compiler doesn't know that at **compile time** - all it sees is the mask (it could be you in the mask, or me - it can't tell the difference).

Comment: The issue you are experiencing is basically the same issue shown at https://dotnetfiddle.net/ol898U . Note that you and I both know that `bob` is a `string` - but the compiler doesn't (it thinks the type is `object` since that is the type of the variable). So it won't let me use `bob.Length`, since `object` doesn't have a `Length` property. This is basically the same as what you are seeing (except `string` is like `List` and `object` is like `IEnumerable`). But, just like with `IEnumerable`, if you call `bob.GetType()` it will return `string`.

Answer (score 1):

[IEnumerable Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a
>   collection of a specified type.

That's it, that's all it does. Now, there are many extension methods that work with `IEnumerable`, though it just so happens `Add` is not one of them

`List<T>`, implements `IEnumerable` which makes sense, and it has the ability to Add.

So from here you have 2 options

1. Return a `List<T>`

   - `public static List<Person> GetPersons()`
2. Enumerate your `IEnumerable` to a `List<T>`

   - `var personList = Person.GetPersons().ToList();`

Which one should you use? Well the fact that you are trying to add something and you are just not enumerating it, or using it in a Linq statement, says you probably should go with option 1

---

> But whenever the caller calls the method and gets the type of the
>   method. It stil shows as System.Collections.Generic.List . Could
>   you explain why GetType is showing as List

Because that was the type created, when you return an `IEnumerable`, you are just casting the `List<T>` as a more fundamental type (in this case an interface). When you call *GetType*, it is telling you what type it is, because it **IS** that type. The compiler still knows what type your created! in-case you want to cast it back.

I think you need to hit the documentation a little more

- [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/)
- [Casting and type conversions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)

Answer (score 0):

The IEnumerable interface is in charge of iterating over the collection, not the storage and the adding/removing that goes on. So to enable adding to the list you can change your return type to `List<Person>` like so:

```
public static List<Person> GetPersons()
[...]
```

And everything should work.

While your return method does indeed return a List, by saying the return type is an IEnumerable you are saying to the user of your function should only iterate, not alter. Which is also why you get the compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable` does not supports adding new element to it.

`IEnumerable` interface from MSDN :

> Exposes an enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a non-generic collection.

Instead of using `IEnumerable<Person>` as a return type of `GetPerson()` function use `List<Person>`.

Like

```
    public static List<Person> GetPersons()
    {
        List<Person> personList = new List<Person>()
                                      {
                                          new Person() { Age = 10, Name = "Vijay"}
                                      };

       return personList;
    }
```